# Cannot resolve method 'getInstanceIdReciever' in 'FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to create Ekart Adnroid application in Android Studio
but i can't solve this error
FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver.getInstanceIdReciever().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {

```
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            String token = (String) instanceIdResult.getToken();
            if (!token.equals(session.getData(Session.KEY_FCM_ID))) {
                UpdateToken((String) token, MainActivity.this);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update token, you needd to use the latest one which is `FirebaseMessaging`.

```
//Save token                        
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
      val androidToken = task.result.toString()
      //Save your token here
    }
}
```